# Azure Resource Graph Explorer - Query Azure VM descriptions, OS, sku - I need to join to columns (OS and sku in one)

Tags: azure, graph, kql

I have a issue. I want to know how can I join two columns in one.

I want to join the "OS" and "sku" columns in one with the name "OS"

This is my KQL:
[Kusto Query on Azure Resource Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFMhd.png)

```
Resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| extend OS = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer
| extend sku = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku
| project OS, sku, name, nic = (properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces)
| mvexpand nic
| project OS, sku, name, nic_id = tostring(nic.id)
| join (
    Resources 
    | where type == "microsoft.network/networkinterfaces" 
    | project nic_id = tostring(id), properties) on nic_id
    | mvexpand ipconfig = (properties.ipConfigurations)
    | extend subnet_resource_id = split(tostring(ipconfig.properties.subnet.id), '/'), ipAddress = ipconfig.properties.privateIPAddress
    | order by name desc
| project vmName=(name), OS, sku, vnetName=subnet_resource_id[8], subnetName=subnet_resource_id[10], ipAddress
```

This is my result:

[image: the result image]

I need like this:

[image: the desired output img]

Can anyone help me, thanks so much.

I've tried to use the "union" operator, but I can't make it work.

I have used these reference link:

[Azure Docs Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/query-language)

[Azure Docs Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)

[Azure Docs Link 3](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/dataexplorer-docs/blob/master/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator.md)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine two strings - you can use strcat() function:

```
 Resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| extend OS = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer
| extend sku = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku
| project OS, sku, name, nic = (properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces)
| mvexpand nic
| project OS, sku, name, nic_id = tostring(nic.id)
| join (
    Resources 
    | where type == "microsoft.network/networkinterfaces" 
    | project nic_id = tostring(id), properties) on nic_id
    | mvexpand ipconfig = (properties.ipConfigurations)
    | extend subnet_resource_id = split(tostring(ipconfig.properties.subnet.id), '/'), ipAddress = ipconfig.properties.privateIPAddress
    | order by name desc
| project vmName=(name), OS = strcat(OS, ' ', sku), vnetName=subnet_resource_id[8], subnetName=subnet_resource_id[10], ipAddress
```

Comment: Woowww @Alexander Sloutsky , thanks so much! It works!!! God bless you.